# To Plot data points in Basemap and skip values which are zero

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Presently I am plotting my data values in Basemap using scatter , but some of the data values are zero, hence when I set the color bar they give me some colored dots even for zero (blue in my case). I would like to have only the data values which are not zero in my plot. I find imshow little complex , I just would just like to provide x , y values and plot the data with colorbar. I want something like vmin to show only values greater than zero.. Could you please suggest your view...

Below is the code

```
    xs, ys = m(lon,lat)
    m.scatter(xs, ys, c=mean)
    c = m.colorbar(location='bottom',pad='7%')
```

Comment: Get rid of them ... `xs, ys = zip(*[v for v in zip(xs, ys) if v[1] !=0 ])`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the 0 values with np.nan (after importing numpy), which will have them not display.

Alternatively, you can used a numpy masked array.